# Is it a good practice to have fat $routeProviders and thin controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Generally in MVC, you would have really fat models and thin controllers for easier testing. Since Angular does not really have a true concept of models, it's hard to just dump all the code somewhere for reuse.

Angular does have services, and we can dump a lot of our API query stuff into there, but I still have chubby controllers because of all the callbacks. I noticed that you can resolve things in the routeProviders, and it seems like I can pull a lot of these things out of the controller and keep it in my routesProvider, but is this a good practice? Resolve always runs before the controller, so what's the general rule when using resolve? I can technically do most of my promises in the controller or the resolve.

Comment: +1 for `chubby controllers` ...gave a me a good laugh

Comment: @charlietfl Glad you enjoyed it, haha.

Answer (score 0):

You can use resolve things in the routeProvider to provide your controller with content or data that is custom to the state. In other words, if you current state suggests preparing load some data specific to namely this state, you need to use resolve in the routeProvider.